# "move" threads to chat?

Tags: discussion, support

I was surprised to see the conversation still in the comments, after accepting the suggestion to move it to Chat.  It copied the messages, not moved them.  Did something go wrong?

Comment: Are you referring to the "let us continue this in chat" migration (that either user in a two-way conversation can trigger after a certain point), or the case where a moderator moves comments to chat?

Comment: The former.  The attempt to add another comment triggered it.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing went wrong. "Moving" threads to chat doesn't actually move them; it copies them to a new chat room and leaves a comment as the person who accepted the suggestion, linking the new chat room.

Admittedly, it is easy to be misled by the wording of the message.

Comment: This is correct. If you feel it's too much clutter, flag the post for moderator attention and request a comments purge.